# Stack Exchange iOS app not working?

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

I'm currently unable to access anything via the Stack Exchange app under iOS; is this a known issue?

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [StackOverflow app not loading content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380819/4642212).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to log out and log back in.

There was a bad deploy after a refactor that made the mobile API think all requests were insecure, causing a variety of automated actions to invalidate your access token.

The change has been reverted and the fix identified.  Basically, Visual Studio's "Find Usaged" feature missed code inside an `#if !DEBUG` block.

Comment: Oh you so crazy visual studio.

Comment: I logged out and back in and still have the same ossue.