# Error on both iOS and Android apps

Tags: support, android-app, ios-app

Since recently (about a week ago), the SE app doesn't work for me any more - either or Android or on iOS.  When I open the app, I see the progress spinner for a short while, after which I get:

- On Android: a blank screen and a white-on-red error message *"Sorry, something went wrong trying to load teh feed. Pull to refresh to try again."*
- On iOS: one hot question with blank screen below and a white-on-dark-blue error message *"Request failed. Tap to retry."*

See screenshots below from both.

I tried on WiFi and 4G - with the same results. I tried rebooting rebooting the phone - with the same results. My Android phone is Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.2. My iOS mobile is an iPhone 6 with iOS 12.1.2.

Is there a way for me to get around this? To start with, are there any logs I can look at to see what's going on?

[image: iOS screenshot]
   
[image: Android screenshot]

Comment: Can you try logging out and back in? Does the problem persist?

Comment: Android app works fine for me, although it's been slower than usual.

Comment: I had a problem where question lists for sites were just completely blank on one phone, while it worked fine on another (both Android). I had to clear the app data to get it working again.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324691/stack-exchange-ios-app-not-working)?

Comment: @AdamLear That did it. Logging off and on again fixed the problem.  I guess the auth token became invalid somehow.

Comment: @AleksG Yeah, we had a bad build go out around that time that bricked auth tokens. Apologies for the inconvenience.